# MVC5 - WebAPI 2 - CamelCase JSON formatter stopped working when Controller changed to return HttpResponseMessage

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

In our Web API 2 application, we configured the JSON formatting globally like this:

```
var jsonformatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;      
jsonformatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

This worked great - JSON was camelcase.., until we changed our controller methods to return a HttpReponseMessage (instead of the response model type directly) like this:

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```

That one change seemed to cause MVC to not use the JSON formatter.  Our JSON is no longer CaemlCase.

Is this the expected/designed behavior or have I not specified the formatter correctly?

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actual method that is called when you use Request.CreateResponse is this:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse<T>(
                                          this HttpRequestMessage request, T value)
{
    return request.CreateResponse<T>(HttpStatusCode.OK, value, configuration: null);
}
```

As you see configuration property is just being set to null.

So you can just manually take configuration from Request object and call another overload like this:

`Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response, Request.GetConfiguration());`

If you are interested in more detail, you can check source code of the framework. CreateResponse is defined [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/HttpRequestMessageExtensions.cs)

Comment: Hmmm.  Thanks for your reply.  But it seems like it is NOT calling my specified formatters now.  Previously I just had "return response;" (this used my camelcase formatter).  Now I use "Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response)" and it is not using my formatter